# Is there a way to quickly kill Silver enemies?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Later in the game, you encounter Silver bokoblins and other enemies.

They seem to have three times the HP of regular enemies and just take a while to beat.

Is there a way to quickly dispatch them? Or should I just run away from them if the loot is not that much better than normal enemies?

Comment: For accuracy's sake I want to point out that these variants are identified as Silver.

Comment: Adjusted question. Didn't remember it was Silver and not White

Comment: Also there's about 6 edits that were made at the same time lol

Comment: The "boring" way is dodging until you trigger a Flurry Rush and going to town on them.

Comment: ...they seem to drown just as fast as other variants, so that's sometimes an option.  Of course, that means the gems they drop sink, but I guess nothing's perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silver enemies are guaranteed to drop at least one gem and sometimes they drop two, so they're typically worth the fight.

As for tactics to make fighting Silver variants easier, they are still susceptible to headshot stuns and double damage. You can stunlock Silver Bokoblins fairly easily with arrow headshots interspersed with your melee strikes. Lightning/shock-based attacks such as Thunderblades or Urbosa's Fury will stun Silver variants just as well as Red or Blue. You can also use shock to disarm them, reducing their damage significantly. And while we're talking elemental, Frost-based attacks will freeze them just as easily. An Ice Rod or Blizzard Rod makes any Silver variant a cakewalk.

If you have Stasis+, you can use that to lock your enemies. Though it won't last for very long, it's enough for you to get in some free hits or get out of the way of an attack.